# Does pandas fillna have column and row number limitations?

Tags: pandas, fillna

I use pandas fillna in a dataframe of 4253532 rows × 151 columns, it doesn't work. The return is the df with no change. I tried different `method`, all leave the df unchanged. 
Same code works well in a 3741814 rows × 4 columns dataframe.

`df2=df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)`

`df.fillna(value=10,inplace=True)`

I tried return a new df and inplace, both don't work. 
I am sure each row has at least one valid value.
Anyone meet the same problem? Does pandas have a limitation?

More information \

df:

```
print(b.to_markdown())

|         |       8000001 |   8000016 |   8000017 |   8000018 |   8000019 |
|--------:|--------------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| 4253527 |   2.00711e+07 |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253528 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253529 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253530 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253531 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
```

data type:

```
b.dtypes

ITEM_OBJECT_ID
8000001    float64
8000016    float64
8000017    float64
8000018    float64
8000019    float64
dtype: object
```

is nan:

```
print(np.isnan(b).to_markdown())

|         |   8000001 |   8000016 |   8000017 |   8000018 |   8000019 |
|--------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| 4253527 |         0 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
| 4253528 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
| 4253529 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
| 4253530 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
| 4253531 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
```

fillna:

```
print(b.fillna(100).to_markdown())

|         |       8000001 |   8000016 |   8000017 |   8000018 |   8000019 |
|--------:|--------------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| 4253527 |   2.00711e+07 |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253528 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253529 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253530 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253531 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |

print(b.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1).to_markdown())

|         |       8000001 |   8000016 |   8000017 |   8000018 |   8000019 |
|--------:|--------------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
| 4253527 |   2.00711e+07 |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253528 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253529 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253530 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
| 4253531 | nan           |       nan |       nan |       nan |       nan |
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Do you get exceptions/do you not get the result you expect... what actually happens?

Comment: Didn't you missed that it returns a new dataframe ? (it is not changed in place) -> df = df.fillna(method="ffill", axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits to pandas as far as I know. I have used the fillna method on dataframes of many millions rows without any trouble.

For example :

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np



df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
                'A' : [random.choice([np.nan] + list(range(10))) for x in range(int(1e6))],
                'B' : [random.choice([np.nan] + list(range(10))) for x in range(int(1e6))],
                'C' : [random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'])  for x in range(int(1e6))]
        }
)
df = df.fillna("bla")
print(
      df[(df.values=="bla").any(axis=1)]
      )
```

It works as well with 1e7 rows. So maybe, this is a trouble in your first dataframe ?

Comment: Thanks! I copy a part of my dataframe and show each step, but I can't find where emerges the trouble.

Comment: Did you try .replace("nan", "dummy")  to chek it was not converted to str ?

Comment: It can't be replaced by b.replace('NaN','str'), but can be replaced by b.replace({np.nan: 'str'}). I tried to run c=b.replace({np.nan: None}) first and then c.fillna(method='ffill') works! I don't know why, while this problem only raise in this df (all dataframes are produced from one script).

Comment: That's strange... Did you try to gather one NaN value in this dataframe (using something like df.loc[0, "blah"])  and print it ? I seem to remember one time when I had trouble with NaN and multiple constructors of NaN (displayed the same inside pandas but not equivalent)...

Comment: They have general attributes of np.nan or None before/after .replace({np.nan: None}). Looks like something goes wrong in .fillna(). Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: You're welcome !  But None is not np.nan. Check how to replace None values using numpy's "where". I've uses it sometime to purge dataframes...